# O365 Outlook addin : Validation issues while publishing on store [4.18]

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins, office-store

I have been trying to publish Phase 2 of my addin on store but the submission failed with following feedback:

> 4.18 Your add-in may not alter, or promote the
>   alteration of, SharePoint or Office except via the
>   Office and SharePoint Add-ins model.
>
> Explanation from Support: We do allow Add-ins that offer additional functionality via interaction with an additional software component, but the core add-in must have features that the end user can avail of without the requirement to download additional software. The add-in must contain functionality on its own without needing the additional software.

But my addin is an extension to a collaboration website platform which people use to do video conferencing and also has desktop application that users can install on their system.

So, one of the option within core addin is to "Make a call" - here the addin pass the arguments to installed desktop application. And here is the requirement to install additional application(which is our company's software only) and User need to install it.

This feature was available in Phase 1 too but that time I didn't received any objection. The only difference earlier our installer was also published on store and now its not available on store and its kept on our website only.

Please suggest me the work around.

Thanks,
Kanak

Answer (score 0):

Office add-ins must provide functionality for the end user within the add-in itself.

Additional functionality may be provided via additional applications; but the add-in itself must contain functionality for users who do not have and/or choose not to acquire the additional application.

Individual components of your add-in (e.g. make a call feature) can rely on additional applications as long as the add-in contains other features which bring value to the Office user.

(Also, please be aware, Add-ins are not allowed to initiate or download executables. Please direct the add-in users to an externally hosted page that provides the instructions and a download link to the executable as opposed to providing it within the add-in directly.)

Comment: Thanks for responding. But this feature was in phase 1 too which was published on store and was validated and approved by MSFT Team.

Regarding value - we have more features that brings value to the user.

Comment: And we can navigate users to our website page where they can download but it doesn't make sense if its already installed - and in plugin we can not know if app is installed in system or not.

Comment: Apps and add-ins published to AppSource must comply with the [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/validation-policies) at the time of submission. If you believe your add-in contains other features which provide value tot the user, then call this detail out in the test notes of your next submission and the team will review.